# Any replacement for "styleWithCSS" for IE11/Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I know there are two posts about this, but one is not what I look for, the other [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646420/stylewithcss-for-ie) it is but it's 7 years old. Maybe there are known methods nowadays.

I'm using Summernote.js Editor and internally, whenever you want to justify text to left, center or right it executes `document.execCommand('command', false, value)`.
The problem is that for Firefox and IE/Edge, this works differently than in WebKit. Every browser behaves in their own way. 
Chrome adds style inline with `"text-align: direction"`, Firefox and IE/Edge adds an attribute called `"align='direction'"`.

After some investigation, I found that you can use the command "styleWithCSS" to transform those deprecated? attributes into inline style attributes. Which was perfect, but it only works on Firefox.

```
document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", 0, true);
```

Looks like this is still being unsopported from Microsoft browser, that in console above returns always false no matter what values you pass as parameters.

Is there any replacement known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to make it work by iterating through the elements within the editor only for IE and Edge and changing the align attribute to style inline with text-align. 
This is how the method looks:

```
var styleWithCSSIE = this.styleWithCSSIE = function() {
      if(/MSIE 10/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /Edge\/\d./i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        var items = $(".note-editable *");
        $.each(items, function(i, element) {
          var $elem = $(element);
          var align = $elem.attr('align') || undefined;

          if(!align) {
            return;
          }

          $elem.css('text-align', align);
          $elem.removeAttr('align');
        });
      }
    };
```

And just used it after summernote.js executes `document.execCommand(sCmd, false, value)`

Comment: Well done. `document.execCommand` has always been poorly planned out and implemented. It's a cross-browser nightmare.

Comment: Yes, i got help from someone on the library github. It was driving me insane! Now im trying to solve a 'bold' issue on headings for FF and Edge. Another nightmare.